# How to let excel VBA only run the next codes after the queries for data connection have finished refreshing?

Tags: excel, powerbi, vba

I realized that even if the `Refresh` of the query is done first and foremost, the code below the refresh query will run even before the database information is extracted completely. This will leave a gap on my analysis.
A sample code is shown below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Entries").Refresh

Total_rows_OCVoucher = Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_AccSummary = Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

x = 1
For j = 2 To Total_rows_OCVoucher
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 1) = Format(Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Cells(j, 2), "Short Date")
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 2) = Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Cells(j, 3)
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 3) = Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Cells(j, 9)
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 4) = "Outflow"
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Cells(j, 2), "mmmm")
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 6) = Year(Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Cells(j, 2))
    Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Compiled Expenses").Cells(Total_rows_AccSummary + x, 7) = Workbooks("Accounting Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Voucher").Cells(j, 1)
    x = x + 1
Next j
```

How do I let all queries to finish computing first before moving on to the next line of code?

Comment: Alter the connection's properties in the UI to not refresh in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Entries").Refresh
```

with:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Entries")
    .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
```